# ValueError: Number of columns must be a positive integer, not 0

Tags: pandas, plot

when i want to execute below code and plot figer

```
scatter_matrix(total_frame)
```

total_frame is a dataframe like this
[image]

the error like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11336\1619863705.py in <module>
      1 total_frame.dropna(how='any')
----> 2 scatter_matrix(total_frame)
      3 plt.show()

~\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_misc.py in scatter_matrix(frame, alpha, figsize, ax, grid, diagonal, marker, density_kwds, hist_kwds, range_padding, **kwargs)
    137         hist_kwds=hist_kwds,
    138         range_padding=range_padding,
--> 139         **kwargs,
    140     )
    141 

~\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\misc.py in scatter_matrix(frame, alpha, figsize, ax, grid, diagonal, marker, density_kwds, hist_kwds, range_padding, **kwds)
     48     n = df.columns.size
     49     naxes = n * n
---> 50     fig, axes = create_subplots(naxes=naxes, figsize=figsize, ax=ax, squeeze=False)
     51 
     52     # no gaps between subplots

~\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\tools.py in create_subplots(naxes, sharex, sharey, squeeze, subplot_kw, ax, layout, layout_type, **fig_kw)
    265 
    266     # Create first subplot separately, so we can share it if requested
--> 267     ax0 = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, 1, **subplot_kw)
    268 
    269     if sharex:

~\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in add_subplot(self, *args, **kwargs)
    770             projection_class, pkw = self._process_projection_requirements(
    771                 *args, **kwargs)
--> 772             ax = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **pkw)
    773             key = (projection_class, pkw)
    774         return self._add_axes_internal(ax, key)

~\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py in __init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs)
     34         self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, [0, 0, 1, 1], **kwargs)
     35         # This will also update the axes position.
---> 36         self.set_subplotspec(SubplotSpec._from_subplot_args(fig, args))
     37 
     38     @_api.deprecated(

~\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py in _from_subplot_args(figure, args)
    595                             f"{len(args)} were given")
    596 
--> 597         gs = GridSpec._check_gridspec_exists(figure, rows, cols)
    598         if gs is None:
    599             gs = GridSpec(rows, cols, figure=figure)

~\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py in _check_gridspec_exists(figure, nrows, ncols)
    223                     return gs
    224         # else gridspec not found:
--> 225         return GridSpec(nrows, ncols, figure=figure)
    226 
    227     def __getitem__(self, key):

~\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py in __init__(self, nrows, ncols, figure, left, bottom, right, top, wspace, hspace, width_ratios, height_ratios)
    385         super().__init__(nrows, ncols,
    386                          width_ratios=width_ratios,
--> 387                          height_ratios=height_ratios)
    388 
    389     _AllowedKeys = ["left", "bottom", "right", "top", "wspace", "hspace"]

~\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py in __init__(self, nrows, ncols, height_ratios, width_ratios)
     51         if not isinstance(ncols, Integral) or ncols <= 0:
     52             raise ValueError(
---> 53                 f"Number of columns must be a positive integer, not {ncols!r}")
     54         self._nrows, self._ncols = nrows, ncols
     55         self.set_height_ratios(height_ratios)

ValueError: Number of columns must be a positive integer, not 0

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

i search such error and don't find anything,please help me!!!!!

Comment: Please post your entire code in the form of text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

i have solved it,
my data's class is object,the function need num,
so i use pd.convert_dtypes() and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).